# Unable to make mask-image to work on Safari browser

Tags: html, css

I have a table row that has the following CSS

```css
.table-row-mask {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<table><tr class="table-row-mask"><td>Test</td></tr></table>
```

It works fine on Chrome, but not Safari.  Any idea how to make it work on Safari?

I'm on Mac with Safari 15.5

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image

Comment: Are you on IOS and if so what version or are you having a problem with another OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that on Windows10 Edge I needed -webkit prefix to the mask, though not on Firefox on Windows.

The -webit was not needed on the current (verion 16...) IOS Safari but seems to be needed on earlier verion of IOS (15.3 and before).

So, safest to have both version in at least for now.

[UPDATE, the original contained a div in the HTML and edited version a table so both shown here].

```css
.table-row-mask {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<div class="table-row-mask">Test</div>

<table><tr class="table-row-mask"><td>Test</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: What you provided is works fine on `div` element.  How about the table <tr class="table-row-mask"> element?

Comment: What problem are you seeing with that? Did you want to target that particular td cell, or all the tds in that row or....?

Comment: I want to target all the tds in that row.  I put the class inside the <tr> element but not working in Safari.

Comment: Working fine for me in IOS Safari (but I only have a 16 version to try). Are you saying it doesn't work on IOS 15.3 or less, even with the -webkit- in there? In which case select each td not just the whole row and see what happens. 
 (.table-row-mask td)